# Java avoid wrapper methods in Decorator

Tags: java, decorator

If you want to add new behaviour to an existing class in Java you can subclass or use the Decorator pattern. If using the Decorator pattern you end up with having to implement all the methods in the interface and just call through to the decorated object:

```
class DecoratedList<T> extends List<T>
{
    List<T> baseList;
    int size() {
        return baseList.size();
    }
    //..like the method above, but for every method on List..

    //The added behaviour
    T secondThing() {
        return baseList.get(1);
    }
}
```

Whereas subclassing you don't need all the boilerplate method passing.

```
class DecoratedList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
{
    //The added behaviour
    T secondThing() {
        return list.get(1);
    }
}
```

the problem with this is that this is can only be used where you need an ArrayList, and only where you have access to the construction of the ArrayList (I know in this example you could copy the elements from an ArrayList to a DecoratedList you create yourself, but that only works for Lists, and wouldn't always be suitable).

Is there some method that you can add to the class that if the method is not found on DecoratedList class, forward it to the baseList, in order to avoid having a bunch of one liner methods that don't do anything new:

```
class DecoratedList<T> extends List<T>
{
    List<T> baseList;

    //pseudocode
    methodNotFound(method, arguments) {
        method.InvokeOn(baseList, arguments);
    }

    //The added behaviour
    T secondThing() {
        return baseList.get(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use proxy's although I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: First, `List<T>` is an interface, not a class; `extends List<T>` should throw a compiler error. To avoid the boilerplate for decorating collections, extend `AbstractList<T>` and implement as needed.

Comment: @dhke Sorry I meant implements List<T>. And that wouldn't work because what if there's a list that doesn't extend AbstractList? (I use List as an example here but this situation also applies to any given interface)

Comment: @Dilip What I said in the last section, though I've clarified it now. Subclassing isn't suitable as I've explained, so is there a way to avoid having a bunch of one line methods that just pass on the call. (Preferably something at compile time)

Comment: @Jonathan you would need a dynamic proxy. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html. But if you know in advance the interface you want to decorate, then definitely go with a regular proxy. Your IDE should help you implement these trivial methods very quickly.